# How to start script with variables using TWebbrowser for Mobile in Delphi XE6

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

if I have this script in my Delphi XE6 mobile project:

```
const
cRoute =
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">


var geocoder;
var map; 
var trafficLayer;
var bikeLayer;
var markersArray = [];



function GotoLatLng(Lat, Lang) { 
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);
map.setCenter(latlng);
PutMarker(Lat, Lang, Lat+","+Lang);
}
</script> 
</head> 
</html>;
```

How can I send values for Lat and Lang from TLocationSensor to this script and show requested map in TWebBrowser on android/ios?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

```
WebBrowser1.EvaluateJavaScript('GotoLatLng('+DelphiLatVar+','+DelphiLongVar+');');
```

[Reference](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/nikolay/2014/04/17/exampleofusingjavascriptforgooglemapsinthedelphixe6/)

Comment: Tnx mate,
i've seen that page but what i do not know is how to pass values from delphi to java script variables.